# no suitable constructor found for Exception(int)

Tags: java, exception

I dont know where my code is throwing its flow to. It has various errors which i dont know how they work. The flow of control through class exception does not support the super arguments for super(int) like it does for super(string) type. I am mostly new to Java and this is a Exception handling program that is user based.

```
import java.util.*;
class invalidbal extends Exception{  
    invalidbal (int balance, int transaction){  
    super(balance); 
    super(transaction);
}
class TestCustomException1{  

static void validate(int balance, int transaction)throws invalidbal{  
        if(balance - transaction < 0)  
            throw new InvalidAgeException("You are not eligible to Transact");  
        else  
            System.out.println("Post transaction your current balance is" + (balance - transaction));  
}  

public static void main(String args[]){  
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to transaction checker");
    System.out.println("Please enter the balance:");
    a = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the transaction:");
    b = s.nextInt();
        try{  
            validate(a,b);  
        }catch(Exception m){System.out.println("Exception occured: "+m);}  

    System.out.println("Thank you for checking!");  
        }  
    }  
}
```

The output is as following.

```
student@ccf128-OptiPlex-755:~$ javac bal.java
bal.java:4: error: no suitable constructor found for Exception(int)
    super(balance); 
    ^
    constructor Exception.Exception(String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to String)
    constructor Exception.Exception(Throwable) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to Throwable)
bal.java:5: error: call to super must be first statement in            constructor
    super(transaction);
     ^
bal.java:9: error: Illegal static declaration in inner class      invalidbal.TestCustomException1
    static void validate(int balance, int transaction)throws invalidbal{  
            ^
  modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations
bal.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
        a = s.nextInt();
        ^
  symbol:   variable a
  location: class invalidbal.TestCustomException1
bal.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
        b = s.nextInt();
        ^
  symbol:   variable b
  location: class invalidbal.TestCustomException1
bal.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
                validate(a,b);  
                         ^
  symbol:   variable a
  location: class invalidbal.TestCustomException1
bal.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
                validate(a,b);  
                       ^
  symbol:   variable b
  location: class invalidbal.TestCustomException1
bal.java:16: error: Illegal static declaration in inner class   invalidbal.TestCustomException1
    public static void main(String args[]){  
                   ^
  modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -  Xdiags:verbose to get full output
8 errors
```

Comment: Here you go https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html#constructor_summary - pick a new constructor to use

Comment: And pick *one* constructor. You can't call `super` twice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java no suitable constructor found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354110/java-no-suitable-constructor-found)

Answer (score 0):

enter code hereAs per the Java doc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) there is no constructor for `Exception` class that takes input as `int`, hence you are getting those errors:

remove follwoing code lines from the `invalidbal()` constructor

```
super(balance); 
super(transaction);
```